# Error while running starcoder pretraining from bigcode megatron-LM

Tags: nlp

I am trying to run the Starcoder pretraining code(/examples/pretrain_bigcode_model.slurm). I created a custom pretrain_starcoder.sh file

```
  #!/bin/bash
  
  GPUS_PER_NODE=2
  # Change for multinode config
  MASTER_ADDR=localhost
  MASTER_PORT=6000
  NNODES=1
  NODE_RANK=0
  WORLD_SIZE=$(($GPUS_PER_NODE*$NNODES))
  
  
  # File path setup
  CHECKPOINT_PATH=/home/jupyter/Satya/Megatron/Model_starcoder/
  TOKENIZER_FILE=/home/jupyter/Satya/Megatron/tokenizer_starcoder/tokenizer.json
  
  mkdir -p $CHECKPOINT_PATH/tensorboard
  
  DISTRIBUTED_ARGS="--nproc_per_node $GPUS_PER_NODE --nnodes $NNODES --master_addr $MASTER_ADDR --master_port $MASTER_PORT"
  
  GPT_ARGS="\
         --tensor-model-parallel-size 1 \
         --pipeline-model-parallel-size 1 \
         --sequence-parallel \
         --num-layers 40 \
         --hidden-size 6144 \
         --num-attention-heads 48 \
         --attention-head-type multiquery \
         --init-method-std 0.01275 \
         --seq-length 8192 \
         --max-position-embeddings 8192 \
         --attention-dropout 0.1 \
         --hidden-dropout 0.1 \
         --micro-batch-size 1 \
         --global-batch-size 512 \
         --lr 0.0003 \
         --min-lr 0.00003 \
         --train-iters 250000 \
         --lr-decay-iters 250000 \
         --lr-decay-style cosine \
         --lr-warmup-iters 2000 \
         --weight-decay .1 \
         --adam-beta2 .95 \
         --clip-grad 1.0 \
         --bf16 \
         --use-flash-attn \
         --fim-rate 0.5 \
         --log-interval 10 \
         --save-interval 2500 \
         --eval-interval 2500 \
         --eval-iters 2 \
         --use-distributed-optimizer \
         --valid-num-workers 0 \
  "
  
  TENSORBOARD_ARGS="--tensorboard-dir ${CHECKPOINT_PATH}/tensorboard"
  
  export NCCL_DEBUG=INFO
  python -m torch.distributed.launch $DISTRIBUTED_ARGS \
          pretrain_gpt.py \
          $GPT_ARGS \
      --tokenizer-type TokenizerFromFile \
      --tokenizer-file $TOKENIZER_FILE \
      --save $CHECKPOINT_PATH \
      --load $CHECKPOINT_PATH \
      #--train-weighted-split-paths-path $WEIGHTS_TRAIN \
      #--valid-weighted-split-paths-path $WEIGHTS_VALID \
      --structured-logs \
      --structured-logs-dir $CHECKPOINT_PATH/logs \
      $TENSORBOARD_ARGS \
      --wandb-entity-name loubnabnl \
      --wandb-project-name bigcode-pretraining \
```

i didn't set the datapath yet.

My current versions are:

```
   CUDA - 11.0
   pytorch - 1.7.0 (i only found 1.7.1 and 1.7.0 for cuda 11.0).
   apex - 1.0
   gcc --version
     gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 9.4.0
     Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   nvcc --version
     nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
     Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
     Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
     Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
     Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
  |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
  |===============================+======================+======================|
  |   0  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:20:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
  | N/A   24C    P0    53W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
  |                               |                      |             Disabled |
  +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  |   1  A100-SXM4-40GB      On   | 00000000:A0:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
  | N/A   25C    P0    50W / 400W |      3MiB / 40537MiB |      0%      Default |
  |                               |                      |             Disabled |
  +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

when i run $ bash ./examples/pretrain_starcoder.sh

```
      Wandb import failed
      Wandb import failed
      using world size: 1, data-parallel-size: 1, tensor-model-parallel size: 1, pipeline-model-parallel size: 1 
      WARNING: overriding default arguments for tokenizer_type:GPT2BPETokenizer                        with tokenizer_type:TokenizerFromFile
      accumulate and all-reduce gradients in fp32 for bfloat16 data type.
      using torch.bfloat16 for parameters ...
      Persistent fused layer norm kernel is supported from pytorch v1.11 (nvidia pytorch container paired with v1.11). Defaulting to no_persist_layer_norm=True
      setting number of micro-batches to constant 512
      > building TokenizerFromFile tokenizer ...
       > padded vocab (size: 49152) with 0 dummy tokens (new size: 49152)
      > initializing tensor model parallel with size 1
      > initializing pipeline model parallel with size 1
      > setting random seeds to 1234 ...
      > initializing model parallel cuda seeds on global rank 0, model parallel rank 0, and data parallel rank 0 with model parallel seed: 3952 and data parallel seed: 1234
      > compiling dataset index builder ...
      make: Entering directory '/tmp/Megatron/megatron/data'
      make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
      make: Leaving directory '/tmp/Megatron/megatron/data'
      >>> done with dataset index builder. Compilation time: 0.114 seconds
      > compiling and loading fused kernels ..
      running on CUDA devices
      Detected CUDA files, patching ldflags
      Emitting ninja build file /tmp/Megatron/megatron/fused_kernels/cuda/build/build.ninja...
      Building extension module scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda...
      Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
      [1/2] /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/local/cuda-11.0/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/include/python3.8 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O3 -std=c++17 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 --use_fast_math -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -c /tmp/Megatron/megatron/fused_kernels/cuda/scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda.cu -o scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda.cuda.o 
      FAILED: scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda.cuda.o 
      /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -isystem /usr/local/cuda-11.0/include -isystem /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/include/python3.8 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -gencode=arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O3 -std=c++17 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 --use_fast_math -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -U__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -c /tmp/Megatron/megatron/fused_kernels/cuda/scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda.cu -o scaled_upper_triang_masked_softmax_cuda.cuda.o 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (const char *const)
                detected during:
                  instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<const char *const &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pytypes.h(1375): here
                  instantiation of "__nv_bool pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::contains(T &&) const [with Derived=pybind11::handle, T=const char *const &]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h(176): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(201): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::handle, pybind11::handle)
                detected during:
                  instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::handle &, pybind11::handle &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pytypes.h(923): here
                  instantiation of "pybind11::str pybind11::str::format(Args &&...) const [with Args=<pybind11::handle &, pybind11::handle &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(755): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::handle, pybind11::handle, pybind11::none, pybind11::str)
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::handle, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::handle, pybind11::handle, pybind11::none, pybind11::str>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(971): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::object, const pybind11::handle)
                detected during:
                  instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::object &, const pybind11::handle &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pytypes.h(923): here
                  instantiation of "pybind11::str pybind11::str::format(Args &&...) const [with Args=<pybind11::object &, const pybind11::handle &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(1401): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::cpp_function)
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::handle, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::cpp_function>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(1407): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::cpp_function, pybind11::none, pybind11::none, const char [1])
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::handle, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::cpp_function, pybind11::none, pybind11::none, const char (&)[1]>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(1418): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::tuple)
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::tuple &>]" 
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/pybind11.h(1812): here
      
      /opt/conda/envs/starcoder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/pybind11/cast.h(2108): error: no instance of overloaded function "pybind11::detail::collect_arguments" matches the argument list
                  argument types are: (pybind11::object)
                detected during instantiation of "pybind11::object pybind11::detail::object_api<Derived>::operator()(Args &&...) const [with Derived=pybind11::detail::accessor<pybind11::detail::accessor_policies::str_attr>, policy=pybind11::return_value_policy::automatic_reference, Args=<pybind11::object &>]"
```

I tried various branches of NVIDIA-apex. updated c++.

I skipped the arguments.